# How can I fix this build error when building Qt 5.7 statically with MinGW?

Tags: windows, qt, compiler-errors, mingw

When I tried to compile `Qt 5.7` statically in order to get a standalone application for windows deployment with all dependencies as mentionned [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) i got the following errors:

> C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\Src\qtbase/qmake/library/qmakebuiltins.cpp: In member function 'QByteArray QMakeEvaluator::getCommandOutput(const QString&) const'
>
> C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\Src\qtbase/qmake/library/qmakebuiltins.cpp:419:94: error: '_popen' was not declared in this scope
>                                   + QLatin1String(" && ") + args).toLocal8Bit().constData(), "r")) {
>
> C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\Src\qtbase/qmake/library/qmakebuiltins.cpp:427:23: error: '_pclose' was not declared in this scope
>            QT_PCLOSE(proc);
>
> Makefile:204: recipe for target 'qmakebuiltins.o' failed
>   mingw32-make: *** [qmakebuiltins.o] Error 1
>   Building qmake failed, return code 2

My aim is to make the final release standalone and size optimized (only ncessary symbols that being used from the libs), also in the link i provided i don't see `MinGw` mentionned, I don't have `nmake` (and don't want to get it).

Comment: Note that the MinGW tools currently do not make it possible to clean away unused parts of an object file, see [this bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11539). Linking statically and stripping most of the stuff out should still be possible though.

Comment: I would also suggest you try [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io/) and its qt5-static package, which provides a ready-to-use statically built Qt, saving you the trouble of building it all.

Comment: @rubenvb i try to avoid unofficial release since it always comes with compatibility problems or project abandon.

Comment: so you build an unofficial release yourself to avoid those problems? The build script is available, so in principle you could build it yourself from that, see [here](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-qt5-static/PKGBUILD). It's not the cleanest example, but well, that's because Qt isn't so quick and easy to build in a normal configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It's open source. All of our recipes and patches are released. MSYS2 has a track record of not being abandonware, but if you find places we can do better then please help out. MSYS2 is highly compatible .. with the rest of MSYS2. We can't promise more than that.